# Is it possible to force blocking process to become non blocking?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen, blocking, nonblocking

I have GUI application. I want to run some process in blocking mode and change its behavior to non-blocking in response to some specific output from stdout. Is it possible to do this without packing my code in thread?

Sample code:

```
    def _run_streamlink(self, url, quality='worst'):
        # run process in blocking mode
        with subprocess.Popen(['streamlink', url, quality, '-p', 'mpv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL) as p:
            while p.stdout:
                # read lines from stdout
                l = p.stdout.readline()
    
                # if certain line is detected then stop blocking main window
                if b'Writing stream to output' in l:
                    # how to force blocking process to become non blockung?
                    p.stdout.close()
                    break
    
        # process exited from loop but it still blocks UI window
```

Comment: Might want to tag your question 'python' as this is clearly python

Comment: Swap out p.stdout.close() for p.kill() or p.terminate()